# Apache 2.4 - ProxyPass and ProxyReserve not working

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I got an issue while trying to re-direct original URL to different URL but preserving the original URL.

Original site: http:/www.mysite.com/recruit
New site: https://www.newsite.com

Here's my vhost.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mysite.com
ServerAlias mysite.com
ServerAdmin root@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/www.mysite.com/


 <Location /recruit>
         ProxyPass https://newsite.com
         ProxyPassReverse https://newsite.com
 </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Restarted httpd successfully, but when accessing `http:/www.mysite.com/recruit`
It said:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /recruit was not found on this server.
```

Comment: Have you tried changing <Location /recruit> to <Location "/recruit">? The examples I see in the docs enclose location paths in quotes.

Comment: I tried that too but it still didn't work.